# Refresh the content of span in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm generating span on my html component inside this for loop

```
<span *ngFor="let list of questions_lists[0].question; let i = index" (click)="changestyle($event)" class="classname">
{{ list }}
</span>
```

On button click i'm trying to load same content but i want to refresh this span also, in my case it is not being refreshed some css like css background color are still shown. As shown in screenshot content is same but i want to remove those color also as i'm reloading the same content.

```
load() {
 this.questions_lists.push(this.questions_lists[this.counter]);
 ...
 ...
}
```

[image]

Any solution Thanks

Comment: You can show hide div based on flag variable using ngIf

Comment: @GRD: No i want to show the same content without using `ngIf` because there are several case also some times i have to pass another content to this array index, this grey background i have applied on initial content load but now i have to remove this style on button click

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz or codepen url ?

Comment: @user3653474 I did not get your point.

Comment: Could you explain better the problem?